# how to get all details about a mysql table using c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to retrieve these info for a mysql table using c#

1) Complete column definitions including name, size and data type, and extra info like null/not null, unsigned,auto increament, default values, if data type is enum, the accepted values

2) All constraints - Primary/Foreign/Check/Unique

3) All indexes

I can get column related basic info using "describe table_name" query against the database.

but how to fetch all these info?

regards,
Anjan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just throw queries against INFORMATION_SCHEMA...

For example, to get column definitions:

```
SELECT   TABLE_NAME
       , COLUMN_NAME
       , DATA_TYPE
       , CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
       , CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH 
       , NUMERIC_PRECISION 
       , NUMERIC_SCALE AS SCALE
       , COLUMN_DEFAULT
       , IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Take a look at [the information schema tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) to get additional info.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable()` method and this is answer only for your 1) option, but this can be done using same connection to your schema, **if your connection string has default database (schema) option set**.
 (You do not need to create seperate connection to INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema).

More info about this method can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable.aspx) and example how to use it [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310107).

To get everything about your schema or databases use `SqlClientMetaDataCollectionNames` class.

More info about class can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlclientmetadatacollectionnames.aspx) and example how to use it [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=202)